# avoiding page from reloading after submitting the form

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I am trying to send from data as email. I am using a PHP mail() to send the email and Ajax to submit the data to avoid the page from reloading. The email is not being sent when I submitting the form. What am I doing wrong? The code somewhat looks like this.

ajax:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: test.php,
        type:'POST',
        success: function(msg){
                alert('Email Sent');
            }                   
        });
    });
```

HTML form:

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0"> 
   <tr> 
        <td>*Your name:</td> 
        <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="32"></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
        <td class="bodytext">*Email address:</td> 
        <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
        <td class="bodytext"> </td> 
        <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Send"></td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

php:

```php
<?php 
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'somugus@gmail.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Fusio Dose customer info'; 
    //$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    //$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    //$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Primary: ".$_POST["primary"]."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Sedcondary: ".$_POST["secondary"]."\r\n";
    //$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

The working example is here

http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Kemail/emailTest1.html

Comment: How far does your script get? Do you get error messages?

Comment: not really. I am not getting any error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize the form and submit it to your PHP page. Try this and it doesn't submit the page:

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function() {  
    alert($(this).serialize()); // check to show that all form data is being submitted
    $.post("test.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){
        alert(data); //check to show that the email sent successfully                        
    });
    return false; // return false to stop the page submitting. You could have the form action set to the same PHP page so if people dont have JS on they can still use the form
});
```

Comment: user1048676- thanks this is very close. I am going to refine on this one. Thanks again

Comment: I have to admit that using serialize is pretty damn clever.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function call to this

```
$('#submit').submit(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  //The rest of your code. 

   $.ajax({
    url: test.php,
    type:'POST',
    data: { name: $("#name").val(), email: $("#email").val() } // and so on
    success: function(msg){
            alert('Email Sent');
        }                   
    });
});



}
```

Comment: @ares- couldnt use the prevent default because it is killing the interactivity in the page. I did try your method

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually passing the values from the form through in the AJAX request, just making an "empty" POST request.  You should look at the AJAX form plugin, it will do the heavy lifting for you:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/